# How to make REGEXP_SUBSTR() function in BigQuery match non-greedy?

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I'm fairly new to regex, and I'm trying to use the function REGEXP_SUBSTR() in BigQuery to extract the "value" portion from a string. The string has two possible forms:

`{A:value, B:someothervalue}` in which case I would use `A:(.*),`

OR

`{B:someothervalue, A:value}` in which case I would use `A:(.*)}`

How can I make one expression that works for both cases? Right now, I'm looking at `A:(.*)[,}]` but this only works when A is on the end. Otherwise, it will always match the } bracket instead of the comma.

I understand this question may be a bit confusing, so I do apologize, and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can use

```js
\bA:([^,}]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Emagog/1). *Details*:

- `\bA:` - `A` as whole word and a `:` char
- `([^,}]+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more chars other than a comma and `}`.